# Create a publishing site collection using Site Template

Tags: publishing-site, site-template

SharePoint 2010 - Publishing Site. I created one with several publishing webs underit. I saved the sitecollection/rootweb as a rootweb.wsp. I created a new webapp, new sitecollection (without picking site template). Then I turned on the publishing features in the new webapp at the site collection level and applied the rootweb.wsp template.

The webapp comes up fine, but I am not able to edit the pages. Edit page gives "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.". I cant even get to the Site Settings | Page Layouts and templates. (Same error). Then I checked the Master Pages gallery. While the files are there, I see the Associated Content Type column set to "#VALUE". So something is messed up with the master page gallery. Checking out some (not all) files gives error "Failed to set the value of Associated Content Type Column".

Any one see such a behaviour with creating a publishing site from a site template? Appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi There. Even though I can't answer your question, I can tell you about my experiences with Sharepoint Site Templates... They dont work as they should! I have an example where Page Titles stick to "Home" when creating sites based on the template.  Anyways, instaed of using Site Templates, I suggest you rather use the Sharepoint Backup tools to export your site with its webs, You can then restore that site with a new name. Go to http://centraladmin/_admin/SiteAndListExport.aspx . This tool allows for just about everything you want to do instead of using Templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a publishing site collection, there are many event handlers that configure the site, deploy lists and libraries and set permissions. When you save your site as template and create a new site collection based on that template, all that included content will be deployed immediately and the event handlers will not work properly. Therefore the option to save the site as template is not available in publishing sites.

What you could do is create your own "Web Template" based on a publishing site definition. You'd have to fit all your modifications into features though, so this is not as easy as saving a site as template.
The only thing that doesn't work with web templates and publishing sites are variations. If you need them, you have to create your own full blown site definition.

Answer (score 1):

Creating publishing sites from a template is not supported.

Comment: I think this should be clarified slightly; Creating publishing sites from a - site - template is not supported. You can still use Web templates to create publishing sites.